# Using PHP code to auto-reset id sequence to order in mysql table after delete

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I want to run two queries in this code. The first delets a row in the mysql table and the second reorders the id value to the right sequence.

```php
if(isset($_POST["image_id"]))
{   
    $file_path = 'files/' . $_POST["image_name"];
    if(unlink($file_path))
    {
        $count= 0;
        $count++;
        $query1 = "DELETE FROM tbl_image WHERE image_id = '".$_POST["image_id"]."'";
        $query2 = "UPDATE 'tbl_image' SET 'image_id' = '$count' " ;
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query1, $query2);
        $statement->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: is this a question or statement?

Comment: is image_id a autoincrement / primary key field ? if so then it is not a good idea. the primary key is to identify a row

Comment: If you delete records from the end then it is easy to re-sequence the auto-increment IDs so that they are once again contiguous ( viz: `ALTER TABLE `tbl_image` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;` ), if you delete randomly then there is no easy way - other than delete the `id` column and re-add. Also, `prepare` will, afaik, only prepare a single sql statement at a time

Comment: Do not reorder IDs.  If you need a sequential number that signifies something then use another field, but this is rarely necessary.

Comment: `the second reorders the id value to the right sequence`  Why? - bad Idea to mess with surrogate key's values.

Comment: Thanks but my code above doesn't even work.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: But your idea is pretty crazy if you think about it. Imagine situation: Someone submitted a request to delete Image ID 10. So now it's deleted. That person thinks it's deleted. Now they want to delete image ID 11. But before , you-renumbered all the images, so that the one with ID 11 now has ID 10, and the one with 12 now has ID 11. So the person who thought they were deleting a picture of a cat, which had ID 11, now actually deletes a picture of a dog, which used to have ID 12 but now has ID 11. And then they are not very pleased about that.

Comment: Or, another situation: a person likes pictures of cats, so they save a link to the picture of the cat on your site. `http://www.example.com/showPicture.php?id=11`, something like that. When they come back to it the next day, they find you've re-numbered all the pictures just to preserve a pointless consecutive sequence, and their link to picure 11 now shows a picture of a dog instead. Not very helpful. I can't think of a single reason why you would want to do this re-numbering, and plenty of reasons why you should **not** want to.

Comment: An ID should uniquely and **permanently** represent the same single specific row in a table, so that you always know which piece of data you will get back when you request that ID. It should have no special meaning beyond that, it's simply a number that we can all agree represents a specific piece of data. Imagine if the government changed your social security number every time someone died, just so that the numbers stayed in sequence with no gaps. It would be chaos. Can you see now why it's a bad idea?